# why i can't install mobione on my pc

Tags: iphone, windows, testing, mobione

this is the [mobione](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/),iPhone Emulator for Windows

the error is :

```
!SESSION 2010-09-11 17:19:34.359 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=zh_CN
Framework arguments:  F:\MobiOne_1.0M9_Installer.exe 0129844033
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 F:\MobiOne_1.0M9_Installer.exe 0129844033

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.531
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.pulse.installer.application.CommonInstallerApplication.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.546
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.546
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.0.200.v20090519 [5] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64 2 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.546
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=win32) (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86_64))
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.546
!MESSAGE Bundle com.genuitec.pulse.client.common.shortcut.win64_3.1.0.v201006161800 [66] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.genuitec.pulse.client.common.shortcut.win64 2 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.546
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (&(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.arch=x86_64))
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.546
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.5.2.v3557f [71] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 2 0 2010-09-11 17:19:36.546
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=win32) (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86_64))
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suggestion is to consult the free MobiOne Studio support forums since full time mobione experts work the forums http://www.genuitec.com/support-mobione/ and your problem has already been resolved there before.

The answer to your problem is you have a corrupted download (EOF is the key info). The latest installer is exactly 130,308,304 bytes. Try redownloading the installer exe maybe using a different download utility as that usually resolves this problem.  http://genuitec.com/mobile/download.html

Wayne